# How to pad multiple tensors with one on main diagonal and zeros elsewhere?

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow, padding, rotational-matrices

I have `R` as 2D rotation matrices of shape `(N,2,2)`. Now I wish to extend each matrix to `(3,3)` 3D rotation matrices, i.e. to put zeros in each `[:,:2,:2]` and put `1` to `[:,2,2]`.

How to do this in tensorflow?

**UPDATE**

I tried this way

```
    R = tf.get_variable(name='R', shape=np.shape(R_value), dtype=tf.float64,
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(R_value))
    eye = tf.eye(np.shape(R_value)[1]+1)
    right_column = eye[:2,2]
    bottom_row = eye[2,:]
    R = tf.concat([R, right_column], 3)
    R = tf.concat([R, bottom_row], 2)
```

but failed, because `concat` doesn't do broadcasting...

**UPDATE 2**

I made explicit broadcasting and also fixed wrong indices in `concat` calls:

```
    R = tf.get_variable(name='R', shape=np.shape(R_value), dtype=tf.float64,
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(R_value))
    eye = tf.eye(np.shape(R_value)[1]+1, dtype=tf.float64)

    right_column = eye[:2,2]
    right_column = tf.expand_dims(right_column, 0)
    right_column = tf.expand_dims(right_column, 2)
    right_column = tf.tile(right_column, (np.shape(R_value)[0], 1, 1))

    bottom_row = eye[2,:]
    bottom_row = tf.expand_dims(bottom_row, 0)
    bottom_row = tf.expand_dims(bottom_row, 0)
    bottom_row = tf.tile(bottom_row, (np.shape(R_value)[0], 1, 1))

    R = tf.concat([R, right_column], 2)
    R = tf.concat([R, bottom_row], 1)
```

The solutions looks rather complex. Are there any simpler ones?

Answer (score 0):

first pad zeros to `[N, 2, 2]` to be `[N, 3, 3]` with `padded = tf.pad(R, [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]])`

then convert `padded[N, 2, 2]` to 1:

since `tf.Tensor` does not support assignment, you can do this with initializing a `np.array`, and then add them together.

```
arr = np.zeros((3, 3)) 
arr[2, 2] = 1
R = padded + arr # broadcast used here
```

now variable `R` is what you need